# Iterate on Fire data (FIRMS) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

i loaded the FIRMS data in Google earth engine for the year 2018 and now want to know for a created AOI, when and if there was a fire there. My idea is to create a loop that shows me in a five-day rhythm whether there is a record in the AOI or not. 
Does anyone have any idea how to set up something like this?

This is the first part of my code:

```
//dataset of FIRMS
var FIRMS = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
              .filterBounds(Greece)
             .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31');
var T21 = FIRMS.mosaic()
             //.clip(StudyArea)
               .select('T21');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your aoi is stored in a variable StudyArea, something like below should work. Remember that loops in Earth Engine is achived via `map()` and conditionals via `filter()`. See [this guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_js_03) for more examples.

```
var filtered = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
  .select('T21')

// Create a list of start days
var dayOfYearList = ee.List.sequence(1, 365, 5)

// Function to convert day to date
var dateFromDayOfYear = function(day) {
  var dateString = ee.String('2018').cat(ee.String(ee.Number(day).toInt()))
  return ee.Date.parse('YYYYD', dateString)
}
// Create a list of start dates
var startDateList = dayOfYearList.map(dateFromDayOfYear)

// Function to return an image consisting of count of valid pixels in the date range
var checkDateRange = function(start) {
  var end = ee.Date(start).advance(5, 'day')
  var dateRangeFiltered = filtered.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end))
  var pixelCount = dateRangeFiltered.reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
  // return the image with a new property for start date, so we can retrieve it later
  return pixelCount.set({start_date: start})
}

// Count total pixels within aoi
var totalPixelCount = function(image) {
  var countDict = ee.Image(image).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: studyArea,
    scale: 1000})
  var totalCount = countDict.get('T21_count')
  // Create a featurecollection with null geometry
  // featurecollection helps because you can filter by properties
  return ee.Feature(null, {'date': ee.Image(image).get('start_date'), 'totalCount': totalCount})
}

// Map the functions over all dates
var yearImages = startDateList.map(checkDateRange);
var yearCounts = ee.FeatureCollection(yearImages.map(totalPixelCount))

// Apply filter on results
var rangesWithNoFires = yearCounts.filter(ee.Filter.eq('totalCount', 0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very usefull. But how can I show the fire indicated for my StudyArea? And how do I know for which day the alarm is displayed?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by showing the fire for study area? You can print the dates for fires using aggregate_array.. see https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/425b5ba58baed51691363565a0387f5b

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your help. That was very helpful. Now that I know the date for the alarm in my StudyArea, I want Sentinel2 data always five days before and five days after the alarm. The goal is to make a comparison between NBR and FIRMS. I have already calculated the NBR for all available Sentinel2 data and attached it to the data as a new band. Is this possible? See code.earthengine.google.com/2d2c456bc3efa5ed6c0cb601aed275ac